# Getting address boundary error when working with pointers in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, function-definition, null-pointer

The following code gives me a `terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`:

```
void rec(int x, int *arr, int *size) {
  if (x < 0) {
      rec(-x, arr, size);
      return;
  }
  arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * ++(*size));
  *(arr + (*size) - 1) = x % 10;
  if (x % 10 != x)
      rec(x / 10, arr, size);
}

int main() {
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *size = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *size = 0;
    rec(20, arr, 0);
}
```

I already figured our that the `arr` counter in the main method won't hold the desired result, but I still can't understand why I'm getting an error.

Comment: Do you know [Hilberto1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14415734/hilberto1)? This code is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603006/c-address-boundary-error-in-small-code-snippet-beginner

Comment: I think this is reposting a closed question

Comment: @Barmar your answer unfortunately didn't solve my problem

Comment: Because you have multiple errors, and I didn't notice the second one.

Comment: Are you the same poster? If the duplicate didn't solve the problem, you should have requested that it be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters these memory allocations

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *size = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

does not make a sense. They are redundant.

You could just write

```
int *arr = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
```

Secondly the variable size is declared but not used because instead of the variable you passed the integer constant 0

```
rec(20, arr, 0);
```

So within the function `rec`

```
void rec(int x, int *arr, int *size);
```

the pointer `size` was initializer by the null pointer constant 0. That is `size` is a null pointer within the function and using a null pointer to access memory results in undefined behavior.

Also you should pass the pointer to the function by reference. Otherwise passing it to the function does not make a great sense because the pointer in main will not be changed.

The code in main could look like

```
int *arr = NULL;
size_t size = 0;

rec( 20, &arr, &size );
```

Pay attention to that you should free all the allocated memory when it will not be used any more.

Correspondingly the function should be declared like

```
void rec(int x, int **arr, size_t *size);
```

Use the type `size_t` instead of the type `int` because this unsigned integer type is the type of the second argument of the function `realloc`.

In general to get the result of realloc you should use an intermediate variable because the function can return a null pointer and the current pointer will be lost.

Also pay attention to that the call of the function is unsafe and can result in an infinite recursion due to this if statement

```
  if (x < 0) {
      rec(-x, arr, size);
      return;
  }
```

when the user passes to the function the value of x equal to `INT_MIN`.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int x = INT_MIN;
    
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    printf( "-x = %d\n", -x );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
x = -2147483648
-x = -2147483648
```

As you can see negating the value of the variable x you get the same negative value. So maybe it is better to declare the first function parameter as having the type `unsigned int`.

Your function can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rec( unsigned int x, unsigned int **arr, size_t *size ) 
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
    
    unsigned int *tmp = realloc( *arr, sizeof( int ) * ++*size );
    int success = tmp != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        *arr = tmp; 
        *( *arr + *size - 1 ) = x % Base;
        if ( x % Base != x )
        {
            success = rec( x / Base, arr, size );
        }
    }
    
    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int *arr = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    
    rec( 123456789, &arr, &size );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%u", *( arr + i ) );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n');
    
    free( arr );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
987654321
```

Comment: does `int *arr = NULL` allocate memory on the heap?

Comment: @Descrates No, it does not. You need to allocate memory in main because that memory is not used and at once is reallocated within the function.

Comment: One last question: is the arr[i][j] notation preferred over *(*(arr + j) + i) because of better readability?

Comment: @Descrates Yes using the subscript operator makes the code more readable.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Is it really feasible to call realloc in every recursion just to increase the size by 4 bytes?  ( Assuming sizeof(int) == 4 )

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Why not?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you are passing `NULL` as third argument:

```
rec(20, arr, 0); // 0 is NULL
```

and you get a segfault dereferencing it:

```
arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * ++(*size)); // here size is `NULL`
```

try with

```
rec(20, arr, size);
```

Comment: sry I'm so lost, I didn't notice that I put a 0 there. Oh god, what a stupid mistake

Comment: Don't beat yourself up, @Descrates!  I once was struggling to figure out why my data processing was giving me crazy results until I remembered that bytes have 8 bits and not 4.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to allocate `size` dynamically. Just declare `int size = 0;` and pass `&size`.